# Bringing columns together when working with Bootstraps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have several textboxes within Bootstrap columns that I want to bring closer to one another, but no matter what I do the distance between textboxes stays the same.

How can I

1. Shorten the distance between the textboxes?
2. Shorten/make more narrow the column background or bring the textbox closer to the outside of a column

Here is the code that I have

```
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="well form-group">
                    <div class="bisformdynamiclabel">Box 1</div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="myclass.box1" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="myclass.box1" class="alert-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="well form-group">
                    <div class="bisformdynamiclabel">Box 2</div>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="myclass.box2" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="myclass.box2" class="alert-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="well form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-1">
                        <div class="bisformdynamiclabel">Box 3</div>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="myclass.box3" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="myclass.box3" class="alert-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Thank you in advance for everyone's help

Comment: Check `class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"` details to see how it effects distance.

Comment: Do you want this to happen on mobile / small screens or on wide screens? The classes you set at your divs are used to set the "width" of elements, meanding that on small devices the width will be (almost) full-width (col-xs-12, although I think it should be col-12 by now) and only 2 of 12 colums on medium devices.